# MSP430 (msp430-gcc) linker undefined reference to

Tags: c, gcc, linker, undefined-reference, msp430

I'm trying to compile my MSP430 project using the Linux msp430-gcc compiler.

When I try to compile it using the CCS IDE it works just fine, but when I try to compile it using the msp430-gcc commandline tool, I get linker errors about functions like calloc and __no_operation.

The beginning of my source file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I compile the program using the following command:

```
msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430g2553 -o test.out source_file.c
```

So it looks like I include the stdio.h and stdlib.h just fine, but I still get linker errors about functions like calloc.
I also tried using arguments like -lc, but that doesn't seem to help.
I read that both stdio and stdlib get included automatically by the compiler so I guess there is no need to use additional arguments for these files.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using? What about `-minrt`?

Comment: @CL. You mean the msp430-gcc version? That's 4.6.3 20120301 (mspgcc LTS 20120406 unpatched). I tried the -minrt argument, but it tells me it's an unrecognized option.

Comment: `msp430_gcc` should use its toolchain includes and libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mspgcc was a fork of gcc; by now, it's horribly outdated.

Nowadays, MSP430 development happens in gcc itself.
You could compile the latest version of gcc yourself, or hope that your distribution has a MSP430 cross compiler, or [get it from TI](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp430-gcc-opensource).

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the .run pre-compiled one from TI's website. I now use the msp430-elf-gcc executable to compile my sources and that seems to work perfectly fine! I did however have to manually direct the compiler to the MSP include files now (eg. msp430g2553.h). Same goes for the msp430g2553 linker files (msp430g2553.ld and msp430g2553_symbols.ld).